# Requirement of Hessian comparison theorem to prove that the squared distance function is strictly geodesically convex.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hessian-matrix

Let $(M,g), dim(M)=n,$ be a complete Riemannian manifold and let $f(x):=d(x,p)^2, p\in M$ being fixed. I'm interested in conditions where $f$ is strictly or weakly geodesically convex. I see the following:

1. Lemma 12.15 from John Lee's "Introduction to Riemannian manifolds" shows that when $(M,g)$ is Cartan-Hadamard, i.e. simply connected with non-positive sectional curvature, $f$ is strictly geodesically convex, i.e. for every geodesic $\gamma\subset M, f\circ \gamma$ is strictly convex, in the sense that its second derivative is strictly positive.

[image]

One of the major ingredients in this proof is the **Hessian comparison theorem** for manifolds with $sec\le 0.$

2. It seems to me that **within a normal neighborhood $U$ of $p,f$ is strictly geodesically convex?** Sorry if it's a trivial question to many, but it's been a while I've studied Riemannian geometry (I switched careers and am coming back to research) and thus I'm a bit rusty on some stuff. The reason I think $f$ is strictly geodesically convex in a normal neighborhood is that w.r.t. a normal chart given by normal coordinates $(x_1\dots x_n)$, $f(x)$ can be written as $\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j^2,$ which has $2.Id_n$ as its Hessian, so $r(x)$ is strictly geodesically convex, but only within $U.$. **But then I'm a bit confused: why do we need the Hessian comparison theorems to conclude for the Cartan-Hadamard manifolds that $f$ is strictly convex?** Won't the fact that $exp_p$ is a global diffeomorphism (Cartan-Hadamard theorem) *alone* prove that we can take the normal neighborhood to be all of $M,$ and thus on all of the tangent space $T_pM, f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j^2,$ which is clearly geodesically convex. **So where does my argument fail?** **Please correct me if my argument is wrong?**
3. Is there any other more general results that deals with convexity of the squared distance function?

Comment: It is false for normal neighborhoods in general. You need to make a normal neighborhood smaller, then you get convexity. You will find a proof in any textbook on Riemannian geometry where convex neighborhoods are discussed.

Comment: The Hessian is not twice the identity map.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks a lot, it does ring a bell - I need to go back and study it!

Comment: @Deane Thank a lot, so even though the squared distance function is represented by the standard squared Euclidean norm, whose Hessian is $2Id,$ the Hessian of the squared distance function is certainly not $2Id$ as operators on the tangent spaces. I see that,, I guess I kind of assumed that one can read off the Hessian of a function from the Hessian in the normal neighborhood, but I see that I made a mistake, I'll go back and think...

Comment: The Hessian at the origin (where the Christoffel symbols are zero), is the Euclidean Hessian. The second derivative in the radial direction is also just $2r$. But the angular derivatives will be different because geodesics on a curved manifold spread apart at different rates than Euclidean geodesics (radial lines).